# 3D Rendering in Google App Engine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, 3d

Is it possible to render any kind of 3D images in Google App Engine (with Backends)?

I'm looking for a Python solution, but I will learn Java if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by render 3d images. Do you mean normal png-s or something interactive? I don't see why it matters if you use app engine or host it elsewhere.

Comment: Normal PNGs. And I want to use Google App Engine, as I don't like to (but I can) manage my own servers.

Comment: Then App Engine has nothing to do with if you server can make 3D images. If you write a server that can build 3D images app engine can host it.

Comment: Are you trying to use app engine as some kind of render factory for a 3D program or something? If so that's an interesting idea :D

Comment: You don't get it at all. I don't have my own servers, and I don't want to buy my own servers. And I want to know if it is possible to do it within the App Engine limits.

Comment: Not a rendering farm :P I am looking to render some simple 3D images with a texture provided by me.

Comment: App Engine is relevant in that many of the available libraries for 3D rendering in Python are written in C. Google App Engine only allows pure Python libraries.

Comment: Yes, that is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine doesn't currently support C modules on the Python runtime. As a result, any rendering code would have to be written entirely in Python, and would be very, very slow. You couldn't take advantage of a GPU, either, since the runtime doesn't supply one.

Your best option, if you care at all about efficiency, is to call out to a server that does the rendering for you.

Comment: As I said before, it could be Java too. I did find a pure Java script that does rendering, but I was browsing from my mobile phone, and I didn't know I would find it useful, so I didn't bookmark it. And I don't really care about efficiency, as the images would be very basic.

Comment: @Bogdacutu You can certainly try it, but you'll probably find it's also slower than native code.

Comment: I know; however, I'll still try.